# Installing WordPress into a sub-directory of WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I installed WordPress within a WordPress website itself without any error. But now when I'm editing any page it is showing error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of `503 () or  net:ERR_ABORTED 503` for page builder assets.
Any suggestions for this error?

Comment: Why do you need two times installation?

Comment: @MahmoodRehman Because I'm going to use a different theme on the new WP instance.

Comment: No I mean if you want multistore like a website or for what purpose you did this? normally two installations in one place didn't work.Just heard from you

Comment: @DeepakT you can use a WordPress multisite network installation and use different themes on each multisite instance. No need for a separate installation

Comment: @MahmoodRehman, okay, I replied an incomplete answer. I want to use another directory because I want a different URL for SEO purposes plus it will have specific tracking scripts. Which is possible via multisite network installation.
And yes two installation at one place are working correctly for now. I didn't make any change. 
I didn't get the thing, I came today and checked page builder is working correctly.

Comment: @jrswgtr, Yes, you''re right. Thank you, I'll go through the documentation. I haven't done it before.